# Using SwiftUI in Xcode 11 playground

Tags: swift-playground, swiftui, xcode11

I know how to use SwiftUI in Xcode 11 in a regular app project, but I was wondering if there was a way to use it in playgrounds as well, even if I couldn't use the live editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, it's pretty easy:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: PlaygroundRootView())

public struct PlaygroundRootView: View {
    public init() {}

    public var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

see more here: 
https://github.com/attoPascal/SwiftUI-Tutorial-Playground

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Mojave besides using `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView` you can draw your SwiftUI view into an image. That way you can have multiple "live views" in your playground.

Check out this article: https://ericasadun.com/2019/06/20/swiftui-render-your-mojave-swiftui-views-on-the-fly/

The sample code is hosted here
https://gist.github.com/erica/fb5005f625207e108836175ff201d8f2

The `renderedImage` utility code (copyright by Erica Sadun!)

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI
extension UIView {
  var renderedImage: UIImage {
    let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.bounds.size).image { context in
      UIColor.lightGray.set(); UIRectFill(bounds)
      context.cgContext.setAlpha(0.75)
      self.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
    }
    return image
  }
}
extension View {
  var renderedImage: UIImage {
    let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 160)))
    let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
    hosting.view.frame = window.frame
    window.rootViewController = hosting
    window.makeKey()
    return hosting.view.renderedImage
  }
}
```